# Recommended way to use google maps API version 2 with current Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

How is the recommended way to create a app which uses Google maps API version 2 within current Android Studio (at the moment version 0.3.2)?

Comment: What are the problems with adding dependency? `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'`

Comment: I used this already but not with a specific version. I use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`. But I always got a error class not found. So I thought I do something wrong. But there was also a error behind this error which directed me to the right solution. With the new play services you have to add `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` to the manifest or it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new play services you have to add

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

to the manifest.